# Sequentially use values from a column in a where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a sports database (cricket, bit like baseball from my American friends) my query to get the most wickets (outs in baseball) in a given season is as follows:

```
select top(5)
S.Season,
TT.Team,
P.LastCommaSpaceFirst,
SUM(PIS.Wickets) AS 'Wickets'
from PlayerInningsSummary PIS
join Personel P on P.PersonID = PIS.PlayerID
join InningsSummary INS on PIS.InningsSummaryID = INS.InningsSummaryID
join Matches M on INS.MatchID = M.MatchID
join Seasons S on M.SeasonID = S.SeasonID
join Teams TT on M.TeamID = TT.TeamID
where TT.Team = '1st XI' --and S.Season = '1973/1974'
group by S.Season, TT.Team, P.LastCommaSpaceFirst
order by Wickets desc
```

So this query gets the top five people who took the most wickets in a season (1973/1974 in this case).

The query works perfectly, but I want to iterate through all the seasons I have (eg:  1974/1975, 1975/1975 and so on).

How can I do this?  I think ROW_OVER with PARTITION BY is the way to go, but I can't figure out how to get that to work.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I think if you include sample data and desired output, it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Seems like CTE might be an alternative, but I'm also unfamiliar with that.

Comment: I can't get the formatting to work :(
@TimBiegeleisen
`Season | Team | Name | Wickets
-----------------------------------------
1973/1974 | 1st XI | SMITH, John | 38
1973/1974 | 1st XI | SMITH, Bill| 32
1973/1974 | 1st XI | SMITH, Phil | 27
1973/1974 | 1st XI | SMITH, Craig | 26
1973/1974 | 1st XI | SMITH, Ben | 21
`

Comment: The answer by @Pdrp is the way to go most likely.

Comment: Sure is, but thank you very much @TimBiegeleisen for taking the time and making the effort to help me - I know my example wasn't the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
Select * from
(
select Row_number() over(Partition by S.Season Order by SUM(PIS.Wickets) desc) as RN
S.Season,
TT.Team,
P.LastCommaSpaceFirst,
SUM(PIS.Wickets) AS 'Wickets'
from PlayerInningsSummary PIS
join Personel P on P.PersonID = PIS.PlayerID
join InningsSummary INS on PIS.InningsSummaryID = INS.InningsSummaryID
join Matches M on INS.MatchID = M.MatchID
join Seasons S on M.SeasonID = S.SeasonID
join Teams TT on M.TeamID = TT.TeamID
where TT.Team = '1st XI' --and S.Season = '1973/1974'
group by S.Season, TT.Team, P.LastCommaSpaceFirst
) A
Where RN <= 5
```

Comment: Sweet Mary and Joseph - That's EXACTLY what I was after!!!  Thank you so much @Prdp

Comment: I'm all ears!  If you could please explain why you would choose one over the other, I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: @Yabbie - sorry for that approach I need sample data of all the tables invloved in that query and expected result. So ignore it

Comment: No problem.  Your first solution works perfectly for me, so I'm happy with that!